# How to return difference in string values from the same column by doing a grouped string comparison in bigquery sql?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table of products with a lot of products with an example like this:

| product | brand |
| --- | --- |
| colgate smile 250gr | colgate |
| colgate fresh breath 250gr | colgate |
| colgate mint 250gr | colgate |
| relx pod pro mango - 1pod | relx |
| relx pod pro lychee - 1pod | relx |
| soju jinro chamisul green grape 360ml | jinro |
| soju jinro chamisul strawberry 360ml | jinro |
| soju jinro chamisul apple grape 360ml | jinro |

into

| product | brand | word |
| --- | --- | --- |
| colgate smile 250gr | colgate | smile |
| colgate fresh breath 250gr | colgate | fresh breath |
| colgate mint 250gr | colgate | mint |
| relx pod pro mango - 1pod | relx | mango |
| relx pod pro lychee - 1pod | relx | lychee |
| soju jinro chamisul green grape 360ml | jinro | green grape |
| soju jinro chamisul strawberry 360ml | jinro | strawberry |
| soju jinro chamisul apple 360ml | jinro | apple |

I want to group by brand and get difference in string and return that as new column.
How do I do a transformation? and check for regexp_contains(str_1, str_2_split)=false and return the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below naïve approach

- split product to distinct word
- identify words that are repeated in all rows of the same brand
- join back to original table and remove (replace with empty string) all such words
- whatever left  - trim it and [optionally] replace occurrence of multiple space with just one space

So, query would look like below

```
with common_words as (
  select brand, 
    r'' || array_to_string(array(
      select word
      from t.words word
      group by word
      having count(*) = cnt
    ), '|') words
  from (
    select brand, count(*) cnt, array_concat_agg(words) words
    from (
      select brand, array(
          select distinct word
          from unnest(split(product, ' ')) word
        ) words
      from your_table
    )
    group by brand
  ) t
)
select product, brand, 
  regexp_replace(trim(regexp_replace(product, words, '')), r'\s+', ' ') as diff
from your_table
join common_words
using (brand)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: hi that makes sense. thank you. however I am getting a Cannot use array subquery with column of type ARRAY<STRING> because nested arrays are not supported at 3

Comment: You can see example of output at the bottom of answer - so make sure your data is as you described it in your question (product STRING, brand STRING) and you use query as it is in the answer